# Binds not updating when messaging between view models using MVVMLight.Messaging

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I'm trying to set the visibility of tab items in a viewmodel from another viewmodel.

I know the binds are correct for I can set the properties (set to false) in the constructor of the new model and they appear / disappear as I wish (setting some to true).

I know that the messenger is working for I can register to wait for a message in the constructor and send a message in the same constructor which get handled by my message callback and the binds update correctly (I can see tabs that were initially set to false).

I know this is not a race condition because I have set Console write lines and see the order in which each line is called. Create Window -> Register Message callback -> Create message and send.

Sending a message from the first ViewModel to the 2nd my callback in the new viewmodel is called and changes the properties but the view does not change (what is hidden stays hidden).

Method from original viewmodel.

```
        private void GenerateWindowedReport()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing View Windowed Report");

            Window ReportWindow = new ReportWindow();

            var msg = new TabVisibility() {
                SuitesReportVisible = IncludeReportSuites,
                TenantRankingsVisible = IncludeReportTenantRanking,
                IndustryReportVisible = IncludeReportIndustry,
                SubmarketBreakdownVisible = IncludeReportSubmarket
            };

            Messenger.Default.Send<TabVisibility>(msg);
            ReportWindow.Show();
        }
```

Class TabVisibility

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Analytics_Module.Messages
{
    class TabVisibility
    {
        public bool SuitesReportVisible { get; set; }
        public bool TenantRankingsVisible { get; set; }
        public bool IndustryReportVisible { get; set; }
        public bool SubmarketBreakdownVisible { get; set; }
    }
}
```

New View (Is contained in the new window created in the first method)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Analytics_Module.Views.TabsReportView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Analytics_Module.Views"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Analytics_Module.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <viewModel:TabsReportViewModel x:Key="vmTabsReport" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource vmTabsReport}}">
        <TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedReportIndex}" >
            <TabItem Header="Search Parameteres" >
                <ContentControl Margin="0,10,0,5" Name="TabContentReportSearchParameters" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Suites Report" 
                     Visibility="{Binding VisibilitySuitesReportTab, 
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                     IsSelected="{Binding VisibilitySuitesReportTab}">
                <ContentControl Name="TabContentReportSuites" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tenant Rankings" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityTenantRankingsTab, 
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <ContentControl Margin="0,10,0,5" Name="TabContentReportTenantRankings" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Industry Breakdown" Visibility="{Binding VisibilityIndustryBreakdownTab, 
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <ContentControl Name="TabContentReportIndustryBreakdown" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Submarket Breakdown" Visibility="{Binding VisibilitySubmarketBreakdownTab, 
                             Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <ContentControl Name="TabContentReportSubmarketBreakdown" />
            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind of new view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Analytics_Module.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TabsReportView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TabsReportView : UserControl
    {
        public TabsReportView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel giving me issues:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Analytics_Module.Messages;
using Analytics_Module.Utillity;
using MVVMLight.Messaging;

namespace Analytics_Module.ViewModels
{
    class TabsReportViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        protected static class TabIndexConstants
        {
            public const int SearchParameters = 0;
            public const int SuitesReport = 1;
            public const int TenantRankings = 2;
            public const int IndustryBreakdown = 3;
            public const int SubmarketBreakdwown = 4;
        }
        public TabsReportViewModel() : base()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TabsreportVM Constructor");
            SelectedReportIndex = TabIndexConstants.SearchParameters;
            VisibilitySuitesReportTab = false;
            VisibilityTenantRankingsTab = false;
            VisibilityIndustryBreakdownTab = false;
            VisibilitySubmarketBreakdownTab = false;

            Messenger.Default.Register<TabVisibility>
                (this, (msgTabVisibility) => SetTabVisibility(msgTabVisibility));

            Console.WriteLine("Message Registered");

            TabVisibility t = new TabVisibility();
            t.IndustryReportVisible = true;
            t.SubmarketBreakdownVisible = true;
            t.SuitesReportVisible = true;
            t.TenantRankingsVisible = true;

            //SetTabVisibility(t);

            //Messenger.Default.Send<TabVisibility>(t);
        }


        public void SetTabVisibility(TabVisibility msgTabVisibility)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tabs Set Visiblity Callback");

            VisibilitySuitesReportTab = (bool) msgTabVisibility.SuitesReportVisible;
            VisibilityTenantRankingsTab = (bool) msgTabVisibility.TenantRankingsVisible;
            VisibilityIndustryBreakdownTab = (bool) msgTabVisibility.IndustryReportVisible;
            VisibilitySubmarketBreakdownTab = (bool)msgTabVisibility.SubmarketBreakdownVisible;

        }


        public int SelectedReportIndex { get; set; }
        public bool VisibilitySuitesReportTab { get; set; }
        public bool VisibilityTenantRankingsTab { get; set; }
        public bool VisibilityIndustryBreakdownTab { get; set; }
        public bool VisibilitySubmarketBreakdownTab { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but this seems more like a hack. All I had to do was to manually trigger the `OnPropertyChanged` for each property.

```
public void SetTabVisibility(MessageTabVisibility msgTabVisibility)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tabs Set Visiblity Callback");

    VisibilitySuitesReportTab = (bool) msgTabVisibility.SuitesReportVisible;
    VisibilityTenantRankingsTab = (bool) msgTabVisibility.TenantRankingsVisible;
    VisibilityIndustryBreakdownTab = (bool) msgTabVisibility.IndustryReportVisible;
    VisibilitySubmarketBreakdownTab = (bool)msgTabVisibility.SubmarketBreakdownVisible;

    Messenger.Default.Unregister<MessageTabVisibility>(this);

    Console.WriteLine("Refresh");
    OnPropertyChanged("VisibilitySuitesReportTab");
    OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityTenantRankingsTab");
    OnPropertyChanged("VisibilityIndustryBreakdownTab");
    OnPropertyChanged("VisibilitySubmarketBreakdownTab");

}
```